# Add content of separated Lists to JTable

Tags: java, swing, list, jtable

How do i populate a JTable with content from 2 different lists?
I have 2 lists with Objects that I get from 2 different tables in a database.
Then I want to put all of them into a single row in a JTable.  So I did 2 for loops, one that adds the content of list1 and the other for loop adds the content of the 2nd List.

The problem is if there's more than one row of data in the database, the second list just keeps repeating the same info

here's my code

```
private void executeHQLQuery() {
    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
            .openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery("from Modelo as m");
        Query q1 = session.createQuery("from Cidade as e");
        List < Modelo > resultList = q.list();
        Integer codModelo = new Integer(resultList.get(0).getCodModelo());
        List < Cidade > resultList2 = q1.list();

        displayResult(codModelo, resultList2, resultList);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        he.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void displayResult(Integer x, List resultList2, List resultList) {
    Vector < String > nomeTabela = new Vector < String > ();
    Vector tableData = new Vector();
    nomeTabela.add("codModelo");
    nomeTabela.add("codCidade");
    nomeTabela.add("nomeCidade");
    nomeTabela.add("estadoCidade");
    nomeTabela.add("paisCidade");
    nomeTabela.add("nomeModelo");
    nomeTabela.add("anoModelo");
    nomeTabela.add("marcaModelo");
    for (Object o: resultList2) { //Works fine
        Cidade c = (Cidade) o;
        Vector < Object > oneRow = new Vector < Object > ();
        oneRow.add(x);
        oneRow.add(c.getCodCidade());
        oneRow.add(c.getNomeCidade());
        oneRow.add(c.getEstadoCidade());
        oneRow.add(c.getPaisCidade());
        for (Object o1: resultList) {
            Modelo m = (Modelo) o1;
            oneRow.add(m.getNomeModelo());
            oneRow.add(m.getAnoModelo());
            oneRow.add(m.getMarca());

        }

        tableData.add(oneRow);
    }
    resultTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(tableData, nomeTabela));
}
```

resultList2 works fine, resultList just keep showing the info from the last Modelo table in database

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing 2 queries, but expecting one of them to change.

If you want resultList to change based on resultList2, then you need to put this query inside the loop of resultList2.

```
Query q1 = session.createQuery("from Cidade as e");
```